# rank of $ACA^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix with $n\sim m^2$ and with rank $m$, and $C$ a $n\times n$ permutation matrix of order 2. Is it true that $ACA^T$ is always invertible? or in some special cases?

If it helps: you may assume $A$ is in row echelon form with all entries being 0 or 1.

Comment: What do you mean by $n\sim m^2$, Adam?

Comment: The amount of columns is about the square of the amount of rows

Comment: ah, I thought that might be it, but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 6):

Not always.  To see this, compute the **compact SVD** of $A$ to obtain 
$$
A = U \Sigma V^T
$$ where $U$ is an $m \times m$ orthogonal matrix, $\Sigma$ is $m \times m$ diagonal matrix with positive diagonal entries corresponding to the $m$ singular values of $A$, and $V$ is $n \times m$ matrix with orthonormal columns.  This gives the decomposition:
$$
A C A^T = U \Sigma V^T C V \Sigma U^T
$$
and so,
$$
\det(A C A^T) = \det(U)^2 \det(\Sigma)^2 \det(V^T C V) 
$$ where $V^T C V$ is an $m \times m$ matrix.

Since $U$ is an $m\times m$ orthogonal matrix and the $m$ singular values of $A$ are positive, we reduced the problem to checking the rank of the $m \times m$ matrix $V^T C V$.  However, a $n \times n$ permutation matrix acting on a set of $m$ orthonormal vectors (where $n>m$) may alter the $m$-dimensional subspace which they span.  In order to avoid this possibility, one must verify that $\text{col}(CV)=\text{col}(V)$, which imposes certain restrictions on the $n \times n$ permutation matrix $C$.

Comment: Thanks! however, that last condition is very much not the situation I have. The thing is that I know the matrix is invertible from other considerations but was trying to give a different proof.

Comment: Since the columns of V (the right singular vectors) form an orthonormal basis for the column space of A', the last condition can be equivalently stated as: the permutation matrix C leaves the column space of A' invariant.  If your matrix is invertible, it must be that this condition is satisfied by your C.